# postgres query count sales and return zero when no sales

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to count the number of sales in range date. example '2021-05-13' AND '2021-05-20'

this is my psql query

```
SELECT date(date_created), count(date_created) as total_count 
FROM users 
WHERE property_id = 1
AND date(date_created) BETWEEN '2021-05-13' AND '2021-05-20'
GROUP BY date(date_created)
ORDER BY date(date_created) DESC
```

The result of the query is this

```
date            |total_count
2021-05-17      |3
2021-05-16      |3
2021-05-15      |4
```

But i need to return `0` with the days without sales. Example

```
date            |total_count
2021-05-20      |0
2021-05-19      |0
2021-05-18      |0
2021-05-17      |3
2021-05-16      |3
2021-05-15      |4
2021-05-14      |0
2021-05-13      |0
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `generate_series()` to generate the missing dates:

```
SELECT gs.date, count(u.date_created) as total_count 
FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2021-05-13'::DATE, '2021-05-20'::date, INTERVAL '1 DAY') gs(date) LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON u.date_created >= gs.date AND
        u.date_created < gs.date + INTERVAL '1 DAY' AND
        u.property_id = 1
GROUP BY gs.date
ORDER BY gs.date DESC;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e94b305630d4f9b48ad80bda29d7ea42) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that the syntax works.

Comment: Sorry, the syntax es correct? I am getting this error `Error in query (7): ERROR: syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 14: ...('2021-05-13'::DATE, '2021-05-20'::DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY) gs(..`

Comment: @Rolly . . . Yes, there was a syntax error.  I neglected the single quotes around the interval constant.